# Infinite loop when nesting have_posts()

Tags: theme-development, loop

I need to create blocks of posts in my theme. So far, I only thought of one possible implementation - a nested loop:

## The Code

```
for ($i = 0; have_posts(); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; have_posts() && $j < 100; $j++) {
        the_post();
        echo "<p>$i, $j</p>";
    }
}
```

## The Problem

Alas, this code generates an endless loop. `have_posts()` returns `true` in the loop on the outside every time.

#### What I tried

Using `the_content()` in the outside loop. It doesn't solve the problem and makes the inside loop iterate one time less. THat's the only thing I thought of.

Comment: [`have_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_posts/) will only ever return `true` or `false`. You're looking for a number. Try something like `$wp_query->post_count` instead (you may have to use `global $wp_query;` first).

Comment: Thank you! That will work.